# Move a project to an exsisting Repo

Tags: git, github

I have a project i have been working on for about a year. I kept the project on git, and committed often so it has a lot of history and a lot of previous data but the original local file has been corrupted. I downloaded the latest version of my project from Github. I want to move this new local project to the existing repo and keep all of its history, how could I do this?

Comment: "downloaded the latest version of my project from Github": is it the same project as the local one? "the original local file has been corrupted": what do you mean by "original file"?

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you mean by original file? Do you mean your local repository has some local commits which is not pushed to the remote while one file of that is corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correct, you are having a local version of repository and a remote one. And both of them have different commit history. Now you want to move files of the remote repository to local repository but preserve the history of local git repository.

History and all the information of a repository is found in `.git` folder which is hidden. If you don't want to bring the history to local git folder, and just want to update files, you can clone to another place, then copy required content to local folder and not touching `.git` folder.

After that using `git status` will tell you which files have been changed. This will not affect the commit history of your local git repo.

Answer (score 0):

I think `rebase` should help here.

I assuming that, you did the changes on a particular branch(say my-work). Firstly , in your existing local modified repo get the latest from your  remote (say `origin`).

```
git pull -- rebase origin master
```

This will bring all the code from your remote master to your local master.

Now, try to apply your changes on top of master using below command

```
git checkout my-work && git rebase master
```